# Can I use UIActivityViewController and FKSDKShareDialog in combination?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is there a way to use `UIActivityViewController` and `FacebookSDK` in combination, so that tapping the Facebook icon launches `FKSDKShareDialog`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use swizzling to uiactivity. Please read this post http://blog.jldagon.me/blog/2015/02/28/hacking-the-default-facebook-uiactivity or you can download an example from here https://github.com/jilouc/CCAFacebookAppActivity